# token is undefined some cases(MERN)

Tags: authentication, cookies, jwt, token, mern

i am trying to implement a profile card,using jwt and cookie-parser.it store in browser cookie but when i try to access it from backend it show me undefined.

**client Side**

```
  import axios from "axios";
  export default function useAxiosPublic() {
    const axiosPublic = axios.create({
      baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
      withCredentials: false,
    });
    return axiosPublic;
  }
```

if i change here **withCredentials true** and another one is

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    credentials: false,
  })
);
```

if i change **crediantials true** then i can access token but as i am using imagebb for upload image then it show me cors policy.

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  //   console.log(req);
  const token = req.cookies.token;
  console.log("res", token);
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(501).json({ message: "token is not valid" });
  }
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
    }
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};

export const userLogin = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "All fields are required" });
  }
  try {
    // const validUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    const validUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!validUser) {
      //   console.log("user not found", validUser);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "No User Found!" });
    }
    // compare with password
    // console.log(validUser);
    // console.log(password);
    // console.log(validUser.password);
    const matchPassword = bycryptjs.compareSync(password, validUser.password);
    // console.log(matchPassword);
    if (!matchPassword) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid credentials" });
    }
    // create a token

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: validUser._id,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
    );
    // console.log(token);
    res
      .status(200)
      .cookie("token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        secure: false,
      })
      .json(validUser);
  } catch (error) {
    // console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Login failed", error });
  }
};
```

thanks for your time and suggestions.